# How to use routing path for the custom url

Tags: angular, routes

How to write the below browser URL into routing.module path. I tried this path: `"disciplines:disciplineId:&disciplineView",`but not able to access.

**Browser URL**
http://localhost:4200/xxx/disciplines?disciplineId=12975&disciplineView=create

**TS Routing**

```
{
    path: "disciplines:disciplineId:&disciplineView",
    component: DisciplinesComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Disciplines',
      breadcrumb: [
        {
          label: 'disciplines',
          url: '/disciplines'
        },
        {
          label: 'page {{customText}}',
          url: ''
        }
      ]
    },
  }
```

Comment: I think you need to use `disciplines` for url path and other is as queryParams. you want this data `disciplineId=12975&disciplineView=create` than get from queryParams

Answer (score 0):

In routing module you have to specify just the main URL (not the queryParams) like this :

```
 {
    path: "disciplines", component: DisciplinesComponent,
 }
```

And when you would like to go at disciplineId=12975&disciplineView=create for exemple you have to specify queryParams like that :

1- with routerLink :

```
 <a [routerLink]="['/disciplines']" [queryParams]="{disciplineId: 12975,disciplineView: 'create' }"
```

2- with navigate methode :

```
this.router.navigate(['disciplines'], {queryParams: {
  disciplineId: 12975, disciplineView: 'create'
 }
})
```